# Create beans with property names as element names?

Tags: spring

I am new to `spring` and happy to see that following works as expected:

```
<bean id="..." class="server.Shell">
  <property name="usableCommands" value="cat"/>
</bean>
```

The above is in the client code, where I have provided the `server.Shell`. Now I would like for the clients to be able to use the following:

```
<shell id="...">
  <usableCommands value="cat"/>
</shell>
```

Is there anything in springframework that I can use to map say an xsd to bean classes? Any other suggestion for easily creating a simple xml based domain language?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a custom [XML Namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html) in Spring that would allow you to customize your configuration XML. If you're looking to create a sort of DSL in your Spring configuration XML, that might be a good place to start.

**UPDATE:**
Check out [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-spring-3-xml) for a general example of how custom namespaces in Spring work. This pattern should hold in OSGi as well -- check out [Section 6.4](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/app-deploy.html) of the Spring OSGi docs for an explanation. If you're new to OSGi, it can be daunting in general. SpringDM can help. Try [here for some background](http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/CommunityEvent2008/27_OSGiCommunityEvent2008-SpringDM-Talk.pdf) and [here for an example](http://java.dzone.com/news/osgi-and-spring-dynamic). Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you know if anything special needs to be done in OSGi environment? I am quite new to this env, do you know of any ready example of this in Spring and OSGi?